# Is there a time delay when the Ethereum merge happens or does it just happen instantly?

Tags: the-merge

During the Ethereum merge of 2022, does it happen instantly or is there a certain delay before it completes the transition? If so won't this affect certain things that are set to expire or unlock if any?

Answer (score 1):

During the Ethereum merge of 2022, the merge will happen instantly after the final POW block is mined. All ETH on the Ethereum network under the current PoW consensus engine will be unaffected by the switch to the proof-of-stake PoS consensus engine once the merge occurs. Users will experience no change in their day-to-day experience using Ethereum, as all changes related to the merge are under the hood and related to the consensus mechanism that secures the network.